# Is any linear combination of two normal random variables normal, if the variables are not independent?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

If two normal random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ are not independent, will any linear combination of them still have a normal distribution?
We have a trivariate random vector $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ where $X_1,X_2$ and $X_3$ are normal.
I am trying to figure out whether

- If $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent, does this imply that X is a trivariate normal random vector.
- If $X_1$ and the vector $(X_2,X_3)$ are independent, does this imply that X is a trivariate normal random vector.
- X always is a trivariate normal random vector

So far I think that 3) X is not a trivariate normal random vector if we can find a linear combination of the components which is not normal. But I am lacking a good example to show this. I also think that the implication in 2) holds, but I dont have any strong arguments yet, just that all linear combinations of the components will be normal because they are independent. For 3 I would think that if a linear combination of two dependent normal variables is not necessarily normal, then the implication does not hold.

Comment: $X_1$ and $(X_1,X_2)$ cannot be independent.

Answer (score 1):

First question: YES

Second question: If you mean that $X_1$ and $(X_2,X_3)$ are independent then the answer is NO: Let $X_3=X_2$ if $|X_2| \leq 1$ and $-X_2$ otherwise. Let $X_1$ be independent of $X_2$. Then your conditions are satisfied but $X$ is not trivariate normal since $X_2+X_3$ does not have a normal distributuion since it is a bounded r.v.  [All my r.v's have $N(0,1)$ distribution].

Comment: Thank you so much!